# Should RESTful services return different data when retrieving multiple items vs a single item

Tags: rest

With a REST API, is it expected that the data returned for a certain resource is always represented exactly the same?

For instance, is it against a spec or common practice to have the following for a list of resources:

```
GET /api/users

{
    userId: 1,
    username: 'User1'
},
{
    userId: 2,
    username: 'User2'
}
```

but when making a call for a single resource, return the following:

```
GET /api/users/1

{
    userId: 1,
    username: 'User1',
    email: 'user1@example.com',
    firstName: 'User',
    lastName: 'One'
}
```

I'm used to only sending data I need over the wire, so it feels strange to me to send everything about a resource back in the response when it's not going to be used.

An example of my concern would be when populating a dropdown using a list of resources IDs and names, there could potentially be a very large amount of unnecessary data sent through.

Comment: All the data is kept indexed. That's why you see this behaviour

Comment: I think this might help you https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#92-serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly ok to have an abbreviated data structure when listing resources vs loading a single resource - in fact, I'd argue that's the expected behavior and most RESTful APIs I've seen/used use this form. After all, if you were to send all of the data when listing resources then why would you even need a separate resource loader apart from someone guessing resource IDs and retrieving the data for them?

The only question is how much should the listing abbreviate the data and that boils down to a typical use case of your service - if it's expected to populate a list of usernames only before digging deeper into the data, ID and username are more than enough.